# Move node from scene root to camera node

Tags: ios, swift, scenekit

I have a node added to the scene root node. The camera is rotating in every direction using gyroscope. I would like that after pressing this node, it would be moved from root node to camera node, so that it will stay in place when camera keeps rotating. How can I get correct new position and rotation, so that after moving this node from root to camera, it will stay in the place in which it was when it was selected? Like relative position from root to camera node.

Comment: You can use `convertPosition(_:to:)` https://developer.apple.com/reference/scenekit/scnnode/1407990-convertposition